# Overriding A MovieClip's Variables in Instances

Tags: actionscript, instance-variables, overriding

Say I have a movieclip and within this movieclip I define some Actionscript variables. e.g.

```
var majorValue:Number = 20;  
var minorValue:Number = 10;
```

By default, every instance of this movieclip on the stage will have these variables, set to these values. Now, lets say I have three instances of this movieclip on the stage, which I'll call "Moe", "Larry" and "Curly". Let's say I want to leave Moe and Larry as default instances of the movieclip, but I want to tweak the "Curly" instance so that it's majorValue is 50, and it's minorValue is 15. How do I go about doing this?

I've tried doing it by specifying:

```
Curly.majorValue = 50;
Curly.minorValue = 15;
```

In the parent timeline, but this doesn't seem to work as it seems the actionscript is executed in the parent clip first and then in the child(ren) clip(s) second. So in other words, my declaration of the "Curly" instance's special values is overridden by the clip's default declarations, which are executed after the parent clip's actionscript.

Does anyone know how to override a movieclip's default variables for a specific instance?

Comment: If you stick your files in a zip somewhere and post the link I'll have a look.

Comment: Okie dokie. Try this:   http://www.filedropper.com/instancevalueexperiment

Answer (score 0):

There's an old tip about working with the timeline which says, "if in doubt, add a key-frame". Actually, even better advice would be to avoid using the timeline altogether if at all possible.

I think your summation of what is happening is probably about right. In effect, you're trying to update the properties on the instance before it has been instantiated properly. When it is instantiated, the values are reset to the defaults.

The solution is to add an additional frame and place the code which sets the properties on the instance in the second frame (along with a `stop` action). This will ensure that the code is executed after the instance has been instantiated.